# Perform an undo action using a script

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have an excellent interactive script which sorts and processes a variety of filetypes from an unsorted folder into newly created directories.

I was wondering how I could write a small script or modify the existing script that so that I could unwind / undo the executed script and its sorting process back to its  (pre sort) state if need be.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
    for i in folder*/; do
        ls -S "$i" > "${i}filelist" 
        cat "${i}filelist" >> ~/desktop/summary.txt
    done
fi
```

Comment: Consider getting in the habit of using the `-r` argument to `read` unless you have a very specific reason not to. Also, consider putting your redirection to `~/desktop/summary.txt` on the `for` loop, not on the individual `cat` command -- no need to re-open the same output file over and over and over.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, for renames specifically, if everything is on the same filesystem, you could just create a hardlink-tree backup of the original structure. That would work with every POSIX-compliant filesystem -- once you've inspected the new structure and decide that you like the result, you delete the backup, and there you are; due to the magic of hardlinks, no actual storage blocks need be allocated (except for the directory objects themselves). That would also protect against situations the reverse-script approach can't fix (like renaming multiple source files to the same destination name).

Comment: ...to be very clear, when I'm doing destructive operations on production infrastructure, I'm very much all about the filesystem-level-snapshot approach or its semantic equivalents (`cp --reflink=always` on btrfs, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a script with an inverse action for each action you're performing, use `printf %q` to quote names in an `eval`-safe manner. For instance:

```
if [[ $undo_log ]]; then
  # at the top of your script: open FD 3 as undo log
  exec 3>"$undo_log"
fi

# later:
mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"

# ...and, if we're generating an undo log, generate a sequence of appropriate commands
if [[ $undo_log ]]; then
  for f in unsorted/*."$extension"
    printf 'mv %q/%q %q\n' "$destination" "${f##*/}" "$f" >&3
  done
fi
```

Comment: Charles if I had to unwind this entire interactive script and the mammoth sort in one go, how would I do this this, is it a special command in terminal to call this inverse  action. regards

Comment: No, there is no such special command. Well -- some filesystems (zfs, btrfs, etc) will have snapshot support, letting you get efficient access to a prior time's version of all of `/home` or such, but that's heavily system-dependent.

Comment: so the unwind / inverse action, would be administered in a  kind of stage by stage process for me .

Comment: Not quite sure I follow the last comment -- is that asking how filesystem snapshotting works? Generally, you tell the filesystem when you want to create a snapshot, and changes since that point are copy-on-write: Instead of overwriting a filesystem block that's changing, it creates a new copy, and leaves the old one around; so you can request either copy, or roll back to the prior snapshot.

Comment: No what I am saying is, If I want to use your answer for the inverse action, it will unwind the entire sort in one go.

Comment: Ahh. Well -- it writes a script, and if you run that whole script, yes, it unwinds everything. If you wanted to just pick individual commands out of it and run them, nothing stopping you from doing that.

Comment: so how do i trigger the unwind from a syntax perspective. if ./a.txt runs the sort in the first instance, how am I calling the inverse with that elegant code of yours nested in my code block

Comment: @SyntaxKiller, if the script were named `run-a-sort` and you ran `undo_log=run-a-sort.undo ./run-a-sort`, then it would be `sh run-a-sort.undo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129450/discussion-between-syntax-killer-and-charles-duffy).